# PHP search function on website. (easy)

Tags: php, search, directory

I have implemented a php search function on a clients website. What I would like it to do is search for files within the website directory for specific pdf files.

However I can't seem to get it to work. If I type in "pdf" into the search box it returns all the files in the directory but if I put in a specific file name then it returns nothing.

Below is the php script I am using:

```
  <?php
    $my_server = "http://www.gwent.org".":".getenv("http://www.gwent.org_80");
    $my_root = getenv("docroot/");
    $s_dirs = array("");
    $hits = null;
    $full_url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $site_url = eregi_replace('customer_information.php', '', $full_url);
    $directory_list = array('sold_msds');
    $s_files = ".pdf"; 
    foreach($directory_list as $dirlist)
    {
        $directory_url = $site_url.$dirlist."/";
        $getDirectory = opendir($dirlist);

        while($dirName = readdir($getDirectory))
            $getdirArray[] = $dirName;

        closedir($getDirectory);

        $dirCount = count($getdirArray);
        sort($getdirArray);

        for($dir=0; $dir < $dirCount; $dir++)
        {
            if (substr($getdirArray[$dir], 0, 1) != ".")
            {
                $label = eregi_replace('_', ' ', $getdirArray[$dir]);

                $directory = $dirlist.'/'.$getdirArray[$dir]."/";
                $complete_url = $site_url.$directory;

                if(is_dir($directory))
                {
                    $myDirectory = opendir($directory);

                    $dirArray = null;

                    while($entryName = readdir($myDirectory))
                        $dirArray[] = $entryName;

                    closedir($myDirectory);

                    $indexCount = count($dirArray);
                    sort($dirArray);
                }
                else
                {
                    $hits++;

                    if(file_exists($dirlist."/".$label))
                    {
                        $fd=fopen($dirlist."/".$label, "r");

                        $text=fread($fd, 50000);

                        $keyword_html = htmlentities($keyword);

                        if(!empty($keyword))
                        {
                            $do=stristr($text, $keyword) || stristr($text, $keyword_pdf);
                        }

                        if($do)
                        {
                            $strip = strip_tags($text);
                            $keyword = preg_quote($keyword);
                            $keyword = str_replace("/","\/","$keyword");
                            $keyword_html = preg_quote($keyword_html);
                            $keyword_html = str_replace("/","\/","$keyword_html");
                            echo "<span>";
                            if(preg_match_all("/((\s\S*){0,3})($keyword|$keyword_html)((\s?\S*){0,3})/i", $strip, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER));
                            {
                                $number=count($match);

                                if($number > 0)
                                {
                                    echo "<a href='".$dirlist."/".$label."'>".$label."</a> (".$number.")";
                                    echo "<br />";
                                }

                                for ($h=0;$h<$number;$h++)
                                {
                                    if (!empty($match[$h][3]))
                                    {
                                        printf("<i><b>..</b> %s<b>%s</b>%s <b>..</b></i>", $match[$h][1], $match[$h][3], $match[$h][4]);

                                    }
                                }


                                echo "</span><br /><br />";
                                if($number > 0):
                                    echo "<hr />";
                                endif;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Many thanks In advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is a *lot* of code -  definitely too much. Please add more detail as to what goes wrong and where exactly. Consider condensing it so it shows only the relevant code. Thanks!

Comment: user1065439
: if you know it's easy, why don't you just do it?

Comment: where are you using $s_files = ".pdf"; ?

Comment: Please don't use `ereg*` functions, use `preg*` instead. At the very least, stick to one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the glob function http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

```
$found = glob("/path/to/dir/*.pdf");
```

Edit: Nevermind your question makes it sound completely different to what your code is doing. Im guessing what i posted is incorrect

Comment: It's not *completely* incorrect, it's a better way to get the file list than the one implemented above. Doesn't directly solve the problem but still not totally unhelpful. Might be better as a comment though...

Comment: Thanks for the comments/answer. I'll level with you all and tell you that I am just a front end designer who had a demanding MD breathing down his neck! Would anyone therefore be able to show/tell me in laymans terms how to put a search function on a website that will search a specific directory for php files by filename only. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simple search, this is not recursive. Give it a directory and it will spit out the found files

```
$files = glob("c:/xampp/htdocs/*.php");
if(empty($files)) {
    echo "No PHP Files Found";
}
else {
    foreach($files as $f) {
        echo "PHP File Found: ".$f."\n";    
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I link this to a search form on the website so that the user could type in the exact filename to bring up the relevant pdf in the directory? thanks